# Why is Lumen view method not working switching from localhost to live server?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

I build API with Lumen.
Also need to display only 2-3 views (database content).
On localhost everything works great but when i move to live server i got error 500 on all my views.
I can display direct content but cannot force it to use view() function and display pages.

*Using laravel blade :* 
On localhost works with route :

```
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
```

my PagesController contain :

```
public function about(){
    return view('pages.about');
}
```

and on localhost everything works using :

```
http://localhost:8000/about
```

but when moved to live server I can only display something directly not via view() method

```
return "text to display";
```

and

```
 return view('pages.about');
```

throws error HTTP 500

What can be a reason why view() stopped working ?
Is there something I am missing in settings ?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs and your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber , storage/logs is empty :( no log files generated

Answer (score 0):

@aynber problem was in denied access to storage folder :)
I did not have permission to save/modify files there and Lumen expects to have access and permissions to that folder and subfolders.
When rights was granted by admin , error http 500 is gone and view() works